# Python application called under apache server is not the same as one run from command line

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, python

So I'm running dokuwiki under Apache on RHEL6 and working on a plugin that calls proc_open in a php script. My problem is that I'm trying to call an application that has been installed locally for apache (under `~/.local/bin`), but the program that gets called from php is a different one. This is probably better understood this way:

When I log in as user `apache`:

`$ sudo su - user`

And I check my application version:

`$ /var/www/.local/bin/rst2html.py --version`

I get:

`rst2html.py (Docutils 0.12 [release], Python 2.6.6, on linux2)`

However, when I make the *same* call in my php application (with proc_open) that runs under apache I get:

`rst2html.py (Docutils 0.6 [release], Python 2.6.6, on linux2)`

Which is the version that is installed globally, i.e., is available to all users.

So what's causing this discrepancy, is there something in the environment that I need to set up?

Note: the python application was installed using `pip`

Comment: How are you testing that it is opening something as root?

Comment: @Zoredache I edited the proc_open call to instead run ``echo \$USER`` which returned 'root'.

Comment: I am not sure that is a valid test. That variable may not be coming from the shell.  Also, I think apache puts the effective user in `APACHE_RUN_USER`, not `USER`.  If you create a file who is the owner of the file?  Or what if you execute `id`, or `whoami` in your passthrough?  You mention using apache, but which method?  The module, or fcgi, cgi, or something else?

Comment: Rather than echo, try using `id` to show the effective user.

Comment: @Zoredache Ah, I didn't know USER was not necessarily valid. Indeed, when I try running ``whomai`` I get the correct ``apache`` user. So I guess that changes my question. I will update it.

Comment: Use the fully qualified path to the binary you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, you are not running it through the web, you are running it from the command line - in that case, the script will run as the user who is running it (indeed, it does not even involve apache here) - thus if you are root when you run it, it will run as root.

If you want to run the script as apache, try something like sudo -u apache "/path/to/script"